# How to iterate numpy array (of tuples) in list manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, iterable-unpacking

I am getting an error `TypeError: Iterator operand or requested dtype holds references, but the REFS_OK flag was not enabled` when iterating numpy array of tuples as below:

```
import numpy as np

tmp = np.empty((), dtype=object)
tmp[()] = (0, 0)
arr = np.full(10, tmp, dtype=object)

for a, b in np.nditer(arr):
    print(a, b)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: @Brian61354270 I copied it from elsewhere and didn't realize that. Is it possible to create (preallocate) np.array of tuples?

Comment: Why are you using `nditer`?

Comment: There's no such thing as an array of tuples.  `numpy` arrays can have a numeric dtype, a string dtype, a compound dtype (`structured array`).  Anything else will be `object` dtype, where the elements are references to objects stored elsewhere in memory.  That's basically the same as a list.

Comment: @Brian61354270, while `tmp` is a 0d array containing a tuple, `arr` also contains that tuple object, not the `tmp` array  See [75] in my answer.  If the elements were 0d arrays, it would display as `array([array((0, 0), dtype=object), array((0, 0), dtype=object)`.  `tmp` is required to avoid a broadcasting error when using `full`.  This isn't trivial kind of array to construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [71]: tmp = np.empty((), dtype=object)
    ...: tmp[()] = (0, 0)
    ...: arr = np.full(10, tmp, dtype=object)
```

You don't need `nditer` to iterate through this array:

```
In [74]: for i in arr:print(i)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
...
(0, 0)
```

`nditer` just makes life more complicated, and isn't any faster, especially for something like `print`.  Who or what recommended `nditer`?

For that matter, you can simply print the array:

```
In [75]: arr
Out[75]: 
array([(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0),
       (0, 0), (0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

But let's look at something else - the `id` of elements of this object dtype array:

```
In [76]: [id(i) for i in arr]
Out[76]: 
[1562261311040,
 1562261311040,
 ...
 1562261311040,
 1562261311040]
```

You made an array with 10 references to the same tuple.  Is that what you intended?  It's the `full` that has done that.

To make a different tuple in each slot, I was going to suggest this list comprehension, but then realized it just produced a 2d array:

```
In [83]: arr1 = np.array([(0,0) for _ in range(5)]); arr1
Out[83]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

To make an object dtype array with actual tuples (different) we have to do something like:

```
In [84]: arr1 = np.empty(5, object); arr1
Out[84]: array([None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)    
In [85]: arr1[:] = [(0,i) for i in range(5)]    
In [86]: arr1
Out[86]: array([(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)], dtype=object)
```

But that brings us back to the basic question - why make an array of tuples in the first place?  What's the point.  `numpy` is best with multidimensional numeric arrays.  Object dtype array are, in many ways, just glorified (or debased) lists.

Answer (score 1):

The error message actually tells you the problem and the fix: you're attempting to iterate over an array of reference types (i.e. objects, `dtype=object`), but you didn't enable [`np.nditer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html) to iterate over reference types.

To fix that set the REFS_OK flag when calling [`np.nditer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html):

```
for x in np.nditer(arr, flags=["refs_ok"]):
    ...
```

Do note that there is also a second issue in your code. After making this fix, `np.nditer` is going to yield references a zero-dimensional array, which can't be unpacked into `a, b` (even though that zero-dimensional array contains a 2-tuple). Instead, you can extract the tuple using [`.item()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) and and unpack it in the loop body:

```
for x in np.nditer(arr, flags=["refs_ok"]):
    a, b = x.item()
```